# F5 and Play button are not working, but F10/F11 do

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ide

For a few days now the IDE has stopped responding to <kbd>F5</kbd>, and clicking the <kbd>play</kbd> button with my mouse also does nothing.  However, if I press <kbd>F10</kbd> or <kbd>F11</kbd> it will step into the code after which I can press <kbd>F5</kbd> and then it runs just fine.

Also, I can right click on the project in the solution explorer and start a new instance of it there without any trouble.

- I have a default project selected
- I have double checked the keyboard shortcuts
- I am on a laptop, but there is no F-Lock key (again, F10/F11 work fine to start the app).

Not sure what to check next??

Comment: You can try attaching another instance of VS and enable break on all exceptions. There may be an exception being thrown/then suppressed that is causing the behavior. Basically, use VS to debug VS. The other (obvious) thing is checking that debugging is enabled in the .config file, although VS always warns when it isn't and you try to debug.

Comment: Thanks.  Debugging is enabled.  And although my default project is currently a website, it was previously set to a WinForms project when this issue started so that pretty much rules that out.  As for debugging VS with VS... I am able to start the project with F10 and from there is acts totally normal so I don't 'think' that would help but I'll definitely give it a shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently had a similar issue with a WPF project after it was branched. You can try going to the solutions properties and double checking that it is set to build under either Startup Project or Project Dependency.

Comment: Thanks.  I just tried both ways but no luck.  +1 for reminding me about the multiple project startup though cause I forgot about that and it's going to come in handy for something else I'm working on.